# NSDictionary and comparing SetObjects

Tags: objective-c

Hi I'm wondering how to compare the contents of the setObjects stored with keys in an NSDictionary:  Here's my code I'm working with:

```
[INNumbers setObject:@"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7" forKey:@"0"];
[INNumbers setObject:@"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" forKey:@"1"];
```

I'm wonder how I would compare the 2 keys and find if there are similar numbers like if 7 occurs in both?

```
//this will get the numbers in the keys for me
     id number1 = [INNumbers objectForKey:@"0"];
     id number2 = [INNumbers objectForKey:@"1"];
```

but I'm not sure how to compare what number1 and number2 retrieve.

Comment: You are comparing two strings in here to find out which numbers are repeated, gonna have a hard time if you want to go that way. Wont it be better to use arrays with numbers instead? It has to be done this way for some weird requirement?

Comment: I just though that it's better to use NSDictionaries, as it is faster.  Plus I'm just trying to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was not force to use strings, I would do it this way:

```
NSArray *nums0 = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSArray *nums1 = @[@3,@4,@5];

NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:nums0];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:nums1]];

NSArray *numsInCommon = [intersection allObjects];
```

numsInCommon will contain @3 that is the number that is in both arrays

Comment: I'm mostly dealing with numbers.  The only reason I'm used strings because I thought thats the only way to deal with numbers and NSDictionary.

Comment: No, there is plenty of ways to deal with numbers and a NSDictionary.

Something similar than what you have could be:
[INNumbers setObject:@[@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7] forKey:@"0"];

That will introduce an array of numbers in a dictionary for the key 0, so it is way easy to compare and use.

Comment: ok so should I look at NSNumber and try again.  Is NSDictionary better for strings?

Comment: NSDictionary is for storing whatever you need to be associated with a key for later retrieval, as long as it is an object NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or your custom objects should be no problem :)

Comment: It's just that coding and inserting @ before every number is quite time consuming when dealing with a lot of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the values stored in the dictionary are string literals, which are hard to parse and test for membership tests repeatedly. Perhaps you wanted to use `NSSet`s:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    NSSet *numbers1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@0, @1, @2, nil];
    NSSet *numbers2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@0, @4, @5, nil];

    if([numbers1 intersectsSet : numbers2]) {
        NSLog(@"The two sets have at least one element in common!");

        /* Let's obtain the intersection: */
        NSSet *common = [numbers1 objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                        if ([numbers2 containsObject:obj]) {
                            return YES;
                        } else {
                            return NO;
                        }
        }];
        for (id o in common) {
            NSLog(@"%@", o);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are NSSets better to use rather than NSArray?

Comment: they are more expensive to build -- so it depends on the use case. for the intersection tests maybe .. we talk about < nanoseconds anyways :D

Comment: thank you this looks the best suitable for what I'm dealing with.

Comment: I'm getting an error with the line if ([numbers2 containsObj:obj]) { its saying No visible @interface for 'NSSet' declares the selector 'containsObj:'

Comment: Sorry how do I use *common?

Comment: See the [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference for details.

Comment: e.g. for(id obj in common) { .. }

Comment: Thanks Daij I tried that but I'm not getting any results.
    ~NSSet *numbers1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:0, 1, 2, nil];
    NSSet *numbers2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:0, 4, 5, 1, nil];
        
    //other code  
      
    id members;
    for (members in common)
    NSLog(@"common contains members %@", members);
            
    ~}